# Closure / Decorator in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, closures, decorator

I want to bind a function to another function to cache its results.
Unfortunately it's not a class, hence I think I cannot use Closures.

I.e. like a decorator in Python.

I want to do this because I cannot modify the function with patching an API code.

So I have a function which gets called very often which always does one SQL query:

```
function api_func() {
    global $wpdb;
    // ... do a query without caching ...
    return $wpdb->get_col(...);
}
```

I want to surround this function by another function cache_func(), so that, whenever api_func() would be called, cache_func() gets called and can once cache the results.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Is `api_func()` written by you or comming from the API? Or have you got a way to override this function? If yes, then I would add a static variable inside it to store your results for a next call. The Drupal CMS has a very neat solution to create functions with cache that you can also clear from outside. Check at [Drupal's example and documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/8.8.x)

Comment: Exactly, that's what I want to do: Add a static var. Unfortunately api_func() is within the Core of a big Wordpress Plugin which I want to keep unpatched to have it safe to updates. That's why I want to have a "closure" function which runs whenever api_func() is called to surround `api_func` itself by a static caching in the surrounding function

Comment: And did the author of the plugin use `add_filter()` or something similar so that someone could change a bit the plugin? If the plugin is missing some optimization, you may could patch it and propose your patch to be included for the next release.

Comment: Unfortunately no - just the DB call and returning the value. MAYBE I could hook directly low level into wpdb->query, but that's rather ugly. Yes, a change request would be good, just didnt yet have good experience with this developer, so not sure whether they wil include it.